# Tensorflow: Slice data and apply Convolution to each slice

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

I've got a 3D volume of input data and would like to apply a ConvNet to each slice.

There is a duplicate of this question. Sadly without answer:
[How to slice a batch and apply an operation on each slice in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35575982/how-to-slice-a-batch-and-apply-an-operation-on-each-slice-in-tensorflow)

In Keras I would use a [TimeDistributed](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/#timedistributed) Layer.
In Tensorflow I couldn't find a direct equivalent.
Instead it seams to me that I have to slice the data myself.

This is my code so far:

```
x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 40, 40, 40, 1])
slices=tf.split(0,40, x)

segmented_slices=[]

for slice in slices:
    # apply a ConvNet to each slice
    reshaped=tf.reshape(slice, (40, 40, 1))         #<-------second error
    # reshaped=tf.reshape(slice, (None, 40, 40, 1)) #<-------third error

    # segmented_slice=conv2d(slice, 3,1,32)         #<-------first error
    segmented_slice=conv2d(reshaped, 3,1,32)
    segmented_slice=conv2d(segmented_slice, 3,32,32)

    #... (more convolutions)

    segmented_slices.append(segmented_slice)

volume=tf.concat(0, segmented_slices)
```

The basic layout is `split` -> ConvNet -> `concat`.
But `split` keeps the dimension. If I simply pass `slice` to the convolution, it complains:

```
ValueError: Shape (?, 40, 40, 40, 1) must have rank 4
```

Therefore I added a reshape. This does indeed reduce the number of dimensions. But apparently it cuts away the batch_size, too. Compared to the first error message, both the question mark and the first 40 are gone.

```
ValueError: Shape (40, 40, 1) must have rank 4
```

It seems like I need to keep the batch_size in the reshape. I tried to add `None` in the tuple. This produces yet another error message:

```
TypeError: Expected int32, got None of type '_Message' instead.
```

Is this the correct way at all ?
Am I supposed to handle this myself ?

Comment: The tf.split at the top of your code is specifying the batch dimension to split on, but it looks like you want to split on one of the size-40 dimensions. Something like `slices=[tf.squeeze(sliced, squeeze_dims=[1]) for sliced in tf.split(1,40, x)]` maybe? That gives me a list of 40 (?, 40, 40, 1) Tensors. As an aside, you can reshape something but preserve one or more unknown dimensions by getting the shape as a Tensor with `tf.shape`.

Answer (score 2):

If the Keras TimeDistributed Layer is what you need, let's look at how it is implemented:

```
input_length = input_shape[1] # assume 2nd dim is the one to slice
# ...
# Shape: (num_samples * timesteps, ...)
inputs = K.reshape(inputs, (-1,) + input_shape[2:])
y = self.layer.call(inputs)  # (num_samples * timesteps, ...)
# Shape: (num_samples, timesteps, ...)
output_shape = self.compute_output_shape(input_shape)
y = K.reshape(y, (-1, input_length) + output_shape[2:])
```

The basic idea is to reshape the tensor in such a way the first and second dimensions (batch and slicing dimensions) are collapsed into one. In other words, each "slice" can be considered an additional data point in the batch. Apply then whatever computation to this new virtual batch and reshape back to original shape at the end.
All these operations are easily implementable in Tensorflow.

Comment: Please read the full question, the asker has signified that he knows about TimeDistributed Layer in Keras and wants to know the pure tensorflow alternative to this.